# Country names ending in "-ia"

Tags: phrase-origin, origin-unknown, language-evolution

Many countries have "land" as a suffix, like England, Poland, Switzerland, etc., which means 'the land of the English', 'the land of the Swiss', etc.

Many other countries have "stan" as a suffix, like Turkmenistan, Kazakhstan, Afghanistan, etc. 'Stan' means land in their language, it became 'the land of the Kazakh', 'the land of the Turkmen', etc.

My question is about "-ia": many counties have "-ia" at the end, like Australia, Serbia, Nigeria, Croatia, Russia, Tunisia, and many more.
Can anyone tell me where that came from, or if it has any meaning?

Comment: Be careful of the word "Paki" - it can be regarded as offensive in the wrong circumstances.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that, shall I remove it from the question?

Comment: @asmgx: Pakistan means "land of the pure". Please edit your body of question.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal to avoid confusion I changed Pakistan example to Turkmenistan, people who will read the questions won't know the land of the pure refers to which country unless they speak that language

Comment: @asmgx: it's better.

Comment: Interestingly, "-stan" ending is Turkic (meaning country) but Turkey's name comes from "Turkia" - land of the turks. (Türkiye in Turkish)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[***-ia*** is a Latin ending](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ia#Latin) ([***-ία*** in Ancient Greek](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%CE%AF%CE%B1#Ancient_Greek)) used to form abstract nouns. In this case, the "abstract" noun referred to a nation, that is, a collection of people and the locations where they lived. For example, the land of the *Germani* was *[Germania](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Germania#Latin)*.

Comment: Is *-ia* cognate somehow with the Hebrew suffix *-ut*?

Comment: Almost certainly not, #mweiss.

Comment: Russian actually still uses "Germania"

Comment: Is *-ia* cognate somehow with the Arabic suffix *-iyya/ ـِيَّة‎*?

Comment: In Italy (Italia, btw) we use it extensively. adding to those the OP listed, there are Francia, Germania, Spagna (>Hispania), Grecia etc.

Comment: @LinuxBlanket That's exactly how we call these countries in Russia as well.

Comment: @Wilson that's about as likely as being cognate to *-ut* as asked by mweiss.

Comment: @Wilson To expand on what Chris said, Arabic and Hebrew are both of the Semitic branch of the Afro-Asiatic language family, and Latin and Greek are both Indo-European languages, which are about as unrelated as you can get; no relationship between those two language families is known, and if there is one, it's far enough in the past that we can't trace any cognates.

Comment: @Hearth in Arabic they use ia in most of the countries names, as LinuxBlanket said they say Italia instead of Italy, Espania for Spain, Almania for Germany, Bretainia for England, Belgikia for Belgium and for many other countries as well Romania, Australia, Urkrania, etc. there must be some kind of relation.

Answer (score 2):

For Nigeria it was birthed from two(2) words namely ‘Niger’ and ‘area’ due to the Niger River crossing into the country and terminating and emptying into the Atlantic Ocean. The British colonialists were impatient mentioning the two and coined’Nigeria’ and this stacked forever…

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (and also seems an unlikely etymology)

Comment: *A historian, Ozibo Ozibo, said historical evidence supports the claim that Flora Shaw suggested [‘Nigeria’ for the ‘Niger Area’](https://dailytrust.com/nigeria60-how-true-is-claim-that-flora-shaw-british-journalist-coined-the-name-nigeria) “in the early days of the British colonial adventurism.”*

Comment: @KillingTime  [The etymology of Nigeria](https://www.npg.org.uk/collections/search/person/mp65594/flora-ne-shaw-lady-lugard?search=sas&sText=Flora+Shaw&OConly=true) appears to be legit, at least according the National Portrait Gallery site. I suppose this answer is saying that Nigeria is the exception that proves the rule.

Answer (score -1):

The academic language of Western Europe was Latin, and the academic language of the Romans was Greek. Thus you get a lot of Greek and Latin forms in European science and geography, including -ia names.

Australia - Austral is from the Latin *Australis*, which means Southern. In the 19th Century the British changed the name from New Holland to Australia.

Russia - of the Rus, the Vikings who settled in Kiev and the surrounding region.

Italia is the Greek geographic term for Italy. The country is *Repubblica Italiana* in Italian.

Comment: It would improve your answer if you could give the definition and/or etymology of the -ia ending. Even though that information is given in other answers, it's good to strive for completeness.

Comment: What precisely does this add to the to-the-point answer already posted, almost four years ago, by Mr. Beadles? New answers to old questions are welcome on this site, but they are expected to make it clear how they differ from what already appears on the same page.

Answer (score -3):

The word "ia" means "of god" or "from god". Ia stands for "Y" (yah-weh), greeks didnt have alphabet "Y" so they used ia instead.. So countries ending with word ia means "OF GOD's or "FROM GOD's"

Comment: Without a supporting link to an authoritative source this answer seems like guesswork, especially in light of [the Greek ending it comes from](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ia#English) which has no derivation from the Hebrew language.